# How to connect to a docker container from the outside world

Tags: docker, boot2docker, dockerfile, dockerhub, docker-registry

I have a web application that is running inside docker container which is running on an Amazon Linux ec2 instance. I would like to connect to that container from the outside world.

How would I do this? I tried using the ec2 instance's ip address and the port that is exposed, such as: `34.21.331.333:7070`

but this would just give me a 404 error.

I also tried exposing the IP of the ec2 instance at run time, such as: `docker run --name myapplication -p 34.21.331.333:7070:7070`

But docker gave me the error: `bind: cannot assign requested address`

Any ideas?

Thanks

EDIT 1:

I am able to connect now, resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In EC2, you have to check the security group for your instance and ensure that the port you want is opened to the world.

Comment: The port is open. The inbound rules has the port that is exposed in the Dockerfile and anyone can access it.